# What does discriminative reranking do in NLP tasks?

Tags: nlp, machine-learning

Recently,i have read about the "discriminative reranking for natural language processing" by Collins.
I'm confused what does the reranking actually do?
Add more global features to the rerank model? or something else?

Answer (score 8):

If you mean [this paper](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/J/J05/J05-1003.pdf), then what is done is the following:

1. train a parser using a generative model, i.e. one where you compute *P*(term | tree) and use Bayes' rule to reverse that and get *P*(tree | term),
2. apply that to get an initial *k*-best ranking of trees from the model,
3. train a second model on features of the desired trees,
4. apply that to re-rank the output from 2.

The reason why the second model is useful is that in generative models (such as naïve Bayes, HMMs, PCFGs), it can be hard to add features other than word identity, because the model would try to predict the probability of the *exact* feature vector instead of the separate features, which might not have occurred in the training data and will have *P*(vector|tree) = 0 and therefore *P*(tree|vector) = 0 (+ smoothing, but the problem remains). This is the eternal NLP problem of data sparsity: you can't build a training corpus that contains every single utterance that you'll want to handle.

Discriminative models such as MaxEnt are much better at handling feature vectors, but take longer to fit and can be more complicated to handle (although CRFs and neural nets have been used to construct parsers as discriminative models). Collins *et al.* try to find a middle ground between the fully generative and fully discriminative approaches.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.Now I'm considering another kind of parsing reranking problem.First,i got a MST parser and get a k-best list of parser tree.Then i use extra feature or other criteria to rerank the tree.Is it sound reasonable?

Comment: Why can't Collins just use the second model? If it's because he can use the global features from the tree generated from the first model,then what is the exactly meaning of the global features of the parsing tree？

Comment: @David: because the second model is a scoring function on trees. You need the first model to generate the trees before you can rank them properly.

Comment: Another point---inference in a PCFG is a lot easier than in the discriminative models. There are standard, exact methods for parsing PCFGs which don't work for discriminative parsers (see http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/CS01.pdf for example). So, the lazy way is to get the exact n-best list from a generative parser and then rerank with a different method which can use global features.